# error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am getting this error with connect function

```
QTimer timer;
QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,this, &MainWindow::draw);
timer.start(1000);
```

both timeout and draw are predefined functions.
How can I solve this?
Even If I use a different function like

```
Sprite *sprite = new Sprite(this);

QTimer timer;
QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,sprite, &Sprite::drawNextBall);
timer.start(1000);


void Sprite::drawNextBall(QPainter &painter)
{
    qDebug() <<"Sprite::drawNextBall() called";
    painter.drawEllipse(x, y, 15, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the error message, signal and slot arguments should match. This is definitely not the case in your example as `QTimer::timeout` has not a `QPainter&` as its first argument:

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.) [[1]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Secondly, `QPainter` should only be used to draw on a `QWidget` inside a [`QWidget::paintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent):

> Warning: When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent(). [[2]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details)

What you probably want is connecting the `QTimer::timeout` signal to the `QWidget::update` (`MainWindow::update` or `Sprite::update`).

**Relevant reading material**

- [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)
- [QPainter - Detailed description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details)